# Libgdx Tap (touch) anywhere

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, touch

I am trying to make a game for Android and to start the game you can tap (touch) anywhere without clicking a sprite or something else.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution

```
if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) { // is called whenever the finger is on screen touch
    // screen is touched : finger on the screen
}
```

Or:

```
if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) { // is called onetime when screen is touch
    // Screen is Touched
}
```